# Do Android Studio need image to run emulator?

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio 3.1 and created a project. I did nothing in it and ran the project. Do I need to install any image?

**Initial Screen - API version**

[image]

Below screen comes when i click on run

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need an image for the emulator or a real device connected via USB, yes.

Comment: Can you please tell how to run the app to test it without any image on real device?

Comment: You will need to switch on developer mode on the device and then connect it via USB. See e.g. https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/ to find out how to enable developer mode.

Comment: refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html @Pankaj

Comment: Is there any offline link to download? It is timing out every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Android version 2.2.2. I uninstalled it and installed version 3. After this, I was unable to download image for emulator.

I finally had to format the drive to get everything done again in first time.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your console to developer mode (i'm windows 10 user)

if you windows 10 user go to **setting - update&security - for developers - 
choose developer mode** at use developer features

Answer (score 1):

You need an emulator if you do not want to run your app directly in an physical android device. However, check if your PC supports or have libraries to run an emulator

Answer (score 0):

NO, just check your PC config to run an emulator. Or you can download an emulator to run your app on Pc.There are many emulators with fewer config requirements.

Comment: any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782746/timeout-error-when-connecting-localhost-api-with-android-studio-on-real-devices ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the image to use simulator, besides, you may also need to change BIOS setting to enable virtualization if you are using Windows OS

Comment: any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782746/timeout-error-when-connecting-localhost-api-with-android-studio-on-real-devices ?