# Issue when trying to access api on localhost through Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using Windows.

I am trying to access (node.js)api running on **localhost** through **USB Device** from Android Studio. I tried to access it like this

> http://localhost:port/authenticate

but did not work.

Also tried to access it like this

> http://IPv4:port/authenticate

Also tried to access it like this

> http://127.0.0.1:port/authenticate

but did not work.

**I have already disabled Firewall.**

> Error Message is : com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Am I still missing anything?

**I can confirm that my api is working perfectly and tested through postman Chrome extension.**

Also tried below code. But still get Timeout error.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return 50000;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return 50000;
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure about your connecting to your localhost and that your firewall is off? is your server listening at port 8080?.... Maybe these links will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782746/timeout-error-when-connecting-localhost-api-with-android-studio-on-real-devices and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994514/volley-timeout-error

Comment: I have added a sentence at the bottom of the question. Thank you very much. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Do you have any additional anti-virus software maybe? 
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994514/volley-timeout-error  The first answer might help.. Is there any authentication? I'm sorry I'm having a hard time picking out the error

Comment: @JoeA : There is no anti virus installed on the machine.

Comment: What network are you connected to on your phone? Can you telnet/open a TCP connection from your phone to the server?

Comment: Did you after alter your code for it to work with postman?

Comment: If you meant user agent specified in the code then no.